# JQuery mobile - how to set the values of a multiple select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, multiple-select

I have a multiple select in jquery mobile.

docs:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html

To get the value I do this

```
    var leerplandoelen = $("#AddLessonForm_leerplandoelen").val();

        var leerplandoelenString = "";
        if(leerplandoelen != null){
            $.each(leerplandoelen, function(i, le){
                if(i!=leerplandoelen.length-1){
                    leerplandoelenString += "\""+le+"\",";
                }else{
                    leerplandoelenString += "\""+le+"\"";
                }
            });
        }
```

To get a string like this  '"1", "2", "3"'.

How can I set the values?

I tried the following:

```
    $('#AddLessonForm_leerplandoelen').val(['3','6','14']).selectmenu('refresh');
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way, read array of selected items. Mark option selected based on `value`

```
// array of values
var selected = ["2", "4"];

$.each(selected, function (i, v) {

  // mark options selected
  $("select option[value='" + v + "']").prop("selected", true);

  // refresh selectmenu
  $("select").selectmenu("refresh");

});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rFe27/)**