# Select Option list only changes is values but not the active label with JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile

I have the following dynamically generated select option list:

```
<select id="select-unidadeMedida" data-mini="true">
<%
/* gera select das unidades de medida dinâmicamente */
Iterator<Unidadesmedida> b = ColbrDatabase.getCollectionUnidadesmedida().iterator();
while (b.hasNext()) {
    Unidadesmedida unidademedida = b.next();
    out.println("<option value='" + unidademedida.getCodigoToText() + "'>" + unidademedida.getCodigoToText() + "</option>");
}
%>
```

I'm trying to change the value of the list with Jquery, with this code:

```
$("#select-unidadeMedida").val("teste");
```

This isn't work properly, the label of the selected option isn't changing, however, if I open the list, the selected value is the correct one that I set with the .val method...

I have tried with text() method, and with a different selector, like : `$("#select-unidadeMedida option:selected")` , but it isn't working too,

what am I missing ?

Comment: $("select-unidadeMedida option:selected") should be $("#select-unidadeMedida option:selected") right?

Comment: @Wilmer , yes, yes, I have made that mistake in the post, but I've tested right in my code, and it didn't work..

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery mobile - how to set the values of a multiple select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494875/jquery-mobile-how-to-set-the-values-of-a-multiple-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should call the change() function.  See the example on jQuery's API documentation under the sub-heading "Get the single value from a single select and an array of values from a multiple select and display their values.":

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: yes, I simply add $("#select-unidadeMedida").change(); and it worked, thanks :)